# JQuery- $(xmlObject).xml does not work in Mozilla but works in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
function parseXml(xml)
{    
    xmlObject= xml;     
    alert(xmlObject.xml);
}
function close(errroMsg)
{
 //Displayed Error Message
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",              
                url: "ServiceProvider.aspx",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: parseXml,
                failure: close   
            }
       );
});
```

In IE-8 the alert(xmlObject.xml) disaplays xml string.
but in Mozilla it displays undefined.
I am using jquery-1.4.2
I was unable to figure out the error.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you try just to call `alert(xml);` ?

Comment: Open up the Firebug console and see what the server response to the AJAX request is--if it is even firing. Could be that IE has laxer XML-parsing and your XML response is malformed.

Comment: I used the firebug. I was able to perform all the operation using xmlObject but the .xml property does not work in Mozilla.

Comment: Tim's answer looks about right, but in the future when developing for Mozilla, I recommend you install and use the Firebug plugin. You could have done something like console.log(xml) and it would have given you the internal structure of the object, letting you see what properties are available. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/

Comment: Even I was facing the same issue. Thanks for posting this question.
And special thanks to Tim, it resolved my issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE has a slightly different implementation of XML documents from  other browsers, one of the differences being that in IE there is an `xml` property of the document.

If you want to serialize the XML into a string in all browsers, you can use the following:

```
function serializeXmlDoc(xmlDoc) {
    if (window.XMLSerializer) {
        return (new window.XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlDoc);
    } else if (typeof xmlDoc.xml != "undefined") {
        return xmlDoc.xml;
    }
}
```

Comment: .xml is Microsoft XMLDOM extension, not available in other browsers normally.

Comment: Thank's to all of you.
Special thanks to Tim Down for finding out the solution which worked for me.